# Fluent NHibernate with development/test/production databases?

Tags: .net, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I was wondering if anyone had developed an approach for using NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate with different databases depending on the application's configuration (similar to Rails' development, test, and production databases).  I believe I could get something working by using methods with conditional attributes, but I would be interested in hearing about experiences with other approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can quite easily tie Fluent NHibernate's configuration to your application config, instead of configuring directly in code; that'd let you substitute your config files depending on your environment.

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(
    SQLiteConfig.Standard
      .ConnnectionString(c => c.FromAppSetting("your-key")))
  .Mappings(/* mappings */)
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```